# React Router always says no route even when they are set up

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-router

I've just started with Meteor and React and most everything I've seen for routers points me to react-router. I've pulled some code from the simple-todos branch and set up a `"/"` route but keep getting the error `router.js:347 There is no route for the path: /`. The page shows the content but I don't understand why this error is showing. I've tried Googling for answers and I can't find anything to help me solve this. I've also tried creating `<Link />` elements to have links send me to other pages and that doesn't work either.

Here is my code:

Routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


import Home from '../../ui/layouts/Home.jsx';
import SignUpPage from '../../ui/pages/SignUpPage.jsx';

export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  </Router>
);
```

Home.jsx

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

import NavBase from '../components/nav/NavBase.jsx';
import Splash from '../components/home/Splash.jsx';
import Snapshot from '../components/home/Snapshot.jsx';
import FooterCTA from '../components/home/FooterCTA.jsx';
import JoinModal from '../components/accounts/JoinModal.jsx';
import LogInModal from '../components/accounts/LogInModal.jsx';

import '../stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../stylesheets/style.css';

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <NavBase />
        <Splash />
        <Snapshot />
        <FooterCTA />
        <LogInModal />

        {this.props.children}

      </div>
    )
  }
}

Home.propTypes = {
  currentUser: React.PropTypes.object,
  children: React.PropTypes.element,
};
```

main.jsx

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from '../imports/startup/client/routes.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Been stuck for a while now and would like to be able to move on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have declared Home as your App layout, then you would have your routes below like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/another" component={Another}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```